# Conditional resizing of JQuery dialog to content height after opening the dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net-3.5

I looked through SO for the better part of the morning but I found nothing to help me do this.

#### The Goal

I was trying to replicate the behavior of the maxHeight option in a JQuery dialog.
This option only applies after the dialog is resized, and I want this property to be applied on opening the dialog, not on resizing.

Unless a patch to a new version is released, the best I can do is a workaround.

#### Information on my project

ASP .NET 3.5 in C#

#### The details

I have to open a dialog containing a gridview (in the div used by the dialog) where normal use can display anything from 1 or 2 lines to dozens.

1. I found a solution on SO that implied setting the "max-height" property on my div instead, but resizing the dialog had an odd effect I was trying to get rid of:
2. If the content is small enough (a list of a couple of lines is common) the dialog is small and can be resized to a greater size. The asp:gridview doesn't move and making the dialog bigger just adds white space under it and to its right.
3. But then once you drag the window edge again to make it smaller, the white area stays the same size instead, sliding up and decreasing the gridview area, eventually reducing it to nothing.
4. Setting the gridview to 100% works to fix that but then making the window bigger with only a couple of line makes eache line dozens of pixels high.
5. So I decided on a fixed height with a non-resizable dialog, that way nothing moves the way it shouldn't, but small content would be packed with white space below it, and we want the window to adjust.

In the end I decided to try to open the dialog to a fixed height and then resize it to fit my content **IF the content div is less than 500px high** in the same function.

My code does not work and I'm at a loss how to get it to or even if it's possible at all.

#### Here is my JS:

```js
function ShowReferedTasks(title, s) {

        // On affiche la div qui constitue le popup dialog
        document.getElementById('litReferedTasks').style.display = '';

        //On crée le dialog à partir de la même div       
        $('#litReferedTasks').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            show: 'drop',
            hide: 'drop',
            width: 800,
            minHeight: 0,
            height: 500,
            title: 'Tâche' + s + ' référée' + s + ' de ' + title            
        });
        /*option 1 (used):*/ var heightDiv = document.getElementById('litReferedTasks').style.height;
        /*option 2:*/ //var heightDiv = $(this).height($('#litReferedTasks').height());
        if (heightDiv < 500)
        {
            $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', 'height', heightDiv);
            /*alternative I tried*/ //$("#dialog").dialog('option', 'height', heightDiv);
        }
    }
```

#### And here is my div:

```html
<div id="litReferedTasks" style="background-color: White; display: none; height:95%;">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvReferedTasks" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvReferedTasks_RowDataBound" Width="97.5%" Visible="false">        
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblNoReferedTasks" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

As you can see I want my function to open the dialog, then determine the size of my div containing the gridview, and if the size is under 500 pixels, I want the dialog height to adjust to the gridview, otherwise for large contents I'll just keep it at 500 pixels high with a scrollbar.

Thanks for any help on this.

## UPDATE 2:

The code below works, but if close my dialog and reopen it the resizing fails on big content.
Any idea why? Basically it only works once until I refresh the page and flush the cache (Ctrl+F5)

## UPDATE 1:

I used a combination of my js script and what @Paul Graffam gave me:

Setting the div to `inline-block` seems to have worked, but then the js did most of the work:

```js
function ShowReferedTasks(title, s) {

    //On crée le dialog à partir de la même div       
    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        show: 'drop',
        hide: 'drop',
        width: 800,
        minHeight: 0,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css({ 'overflow-y': 'auto' });
        },
        title: 'Tâche' + s + ' référée' + s + ' de ' + title
    });
    // Resizes the dialog to fit the content up to 500px, after which it overflows automatically.
    var heightDiv = $('#litReferedTasks').height();
    if (heightDiv > 450) $('#litReferedTasks').dialog('option', 'height', 500);
}
```

The div then fills the whole dialog and overflows when it becomes bigger than it.
The dialog is opened to fit the div at first, no matter how big it is, but then looks at the size of the div and resizes the dialog down to 500px if it is larger than that.

It looks like it successfully does what I want it to, withtout the resizing restrictions and issues that come with using `max-height` on the div.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way I figured out to get this to work was to set the css of the dialogue div to have a `max-height` set to 500px and then you can remove the height settings inside the dialog. This way anything past 500px will be set to overflow while anything smaller than that will automatically resize as the height is now defaulting to auto.

Since gridview uses tables I believe it is important though to set the display of the div to `display: inline-block;` and remove the line that sets the display to nothing.

I set up an example with some of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rrAJM/1/

Also, I noticed you keep using `document.getElementById` but since you are using jQuery there is no need for that. Instead you can select your element by doing this: `$('#litReferedTasks')`

For instance `document.getElementById('litReferedTasks').style.height;` becomes `$('#litReferedTasks').height();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. However I did try using the max-height property on the div, and it worked fine, but some serious issues with resizing popped up, that I mention in my post. For one, resizing the dialog to a height over 500px leaves the div with scrollbars when it overflows but not filling the whole div, instead padding the space with white. Then resizing the dialog again but to a smaller size, instead of cropping the white area out, crops the div out and leaves the white.

Comment: This is why I tried replicating the maxHeight option on the dialog but on opening it, not on resizing. That way the content still fits the window no matter what size it is but if really big content is displayed the window won't open to a size that goes below the screen (and that you can't resize).

Do you know if the JQuery folks are going to release something to that effect? Like a new option or an amendment to the maxHeight option?

Comment: I made these screenshots to be clearer in my explanation: as you can see the dialog resize doesn't get along with the div size properties: http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8548/under500.jpg

http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/6080/over500.jpg